# Cannot set kubelet healthz bind address with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I am trying to configure the kubelet's healthz bind address as follows:

```
kubeadm init --config <(cat <<EOF
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: MasterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: stable-1.11
kubeletConfiguration:
  healthzBindAddress: 0.0.0.0
EOF
)
```

but I get the following

```
# cat /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml  | grep healthz
healthzBindAddress: 127.0.0.1
healthzPort: 10248
```

Am I missing something?

```
# kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.7", GitCommit:"65ecaf0671341311ce6aea0edab46ee69f65d59e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-01-24T19:29:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ***Kubernetes v1.13***, you can get the configuration from kubeadm

```
kubeadm config print init-defaults --component-configs KubeProxyConfiguration,KubeletConfiguration > kubeadm-init.config
```

Edit the `--healthz-bind-address 0.0.0.0`, the IP address for the healthz server to serve on (set to 0.0.0.0 for all IPv4 interfaces and `::` for all IPv6 interfaces) (default 127.0.0.1).

And upload it `kubeadm config upload from-file [flags]`.

You can refer to the Kubernetes documentation for [kubeadm config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/).

**EDIT**

***In Kubernetes v1.11***, option `--component-configs` was called `--api-objects` and available value were `MasterConfiguration`, `NodeConfiguration`.

This is referenced in the Kubernetes v1.11 documentation for [kubeadm config](https://v1-11.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/#cmd-config-print-default).

Comment: This doesn't work for me `error: unknown flag: --component-configs`. See kubeadm version info at the bottom of the question description

Comment: @dippynark I've edited my answer and added information for your k8s version